# Restify and semver wildcards

Tags: node.js, restify

**Question:** How do you specify a wildcard semvar in your accept-version header? (Restify 2.5.0)

**The Goal:** Accept 1.x.x. Looking at the documentation it looks like this is achieved by setting the semver to ~1 or 1.x. However Restify does not seem to handle this.

**Server:**

```
  var server = restify.createServer({
            version: '1.1.0',...
```

**Route:**

```
  server.get({
                    path: /^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.~-]+)\/(.*)/,
                    version: '1.x' // also tried '~1'
            },
            function(req, res, next){
                    req.log.debug(req.params,'Request');
                    res.send(req.params);
    });
```

**The result:**

```
{"code":"InvalidVersion","message":"* is not supported by GET /sys/blah"}
```

I was able to get this working by setting the `routes version to '1.0.5'`(Example in range) and then specifying the `clients accept-version to ~1`, however, it seems like it would be better suited to set a wildcard on the server side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should be the authority for the version it is exposing so it doesn't make sense for it to be fuzzy/reasonable close (using the tilde prefix).

Restify is using [semver](http://semver.org/) for exposing versions (more specifically [node-semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver)) so ~1 isn't a valid version.  As you've discovered, the client can ask for as specific a version it would like or ask for a range.